# Install pygame on windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am using windows 8.1 with python 3.4 installed. I want to install pygame on my computer. I download `pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl` and try to install it like this

```
C:\Users\hp pc\Downloads>pip install  pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```

but it shows an error like this

```
pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
```

Is it a problem with my windows?

Kindly help me to fix it if there is any way to fix it.

Comment: You can get a .msi or .exe to install pygame, download links at [pygame.org](http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml).

Comment: I can't find any 64 bit version that  supported by python 3.4 in there home page

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are no 64 bit version, unfortunately, as the page states "windows 64bit users note: use the 32bit python with this 32bit pygame". The last sentence implies there are some 64 bit binaries for python 2.7, but I haven't tested them.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had the same problems. I Just used the normal pygame download (http://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) and it worked just fine despite not being 64bit

Here is a link a link for the unafishal download that may have what you are looking for: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

hope you can get it to work for you (-:

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also on my "windows 8 64bit" with the 64 bit version of pygame. Which only runs on a 64bit python installation, I had at one time or another installed both versions.

To fix it  I had to uninstall then reinstall the 64 bit Python and get it from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

Then I followed this guide for [Installing the Windows 64-bit Version of Pygame](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/03/installing-the-windows-64-bit-version-of-pygame/)

then I installed the wheel on windows 8 you need to remember to use the full path and 3.4 already had pip included

```
c:\python34\scripts\pip install c:\python34\scripts\pygame-1.9.2a0-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
```